# Android nested library structure, access method in nested library from the main application

Tags: android, gradle, android-library

Is it possible to access a library's dependencies through the main application.

I have the following library structure right now.

- Main application:

  - Main library
  - LibA
  - LibB

Main library then have the following dependencies

- Main library:

  - LibA
  - LibB

But i want the following structure instead

- Main application:

  - Main library
- Main library:

  - LibA
  - LibB

And then Main application should be able to access methods in LibA and LibB, so i only have to include Main library as a dependency in the main application.

I'm using gradle to build my application.

Comment: any progress? I have same problem and I'm searching but no result yet.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on how you package up your main library.
Local dependencies (stuff in libs) get packaged up as part of the aar

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer, unfortunately there are no local dependencies, everything is retrieved through maven repositories. Is there any way to include it in the aar then? @MrChaz

Comment: If you can help me, please answer! :)

Comment: Hi, I don't know of a way to do it properly. It might be possible to do something that takes the contents of the exploded-aar directory in /build but that doesn't sounds like a good idea.